# How to solve error of a bunch of broken packages due to "S3method & number of columns of matrices must match"

Tags: r

Recently when installing new package, the "S3methods" issues jumps up. Trying to find solutions for it as [Error-in-rbind-info-getNamespaceInfo-env-quot-S3methods](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Error-in-rbind-info-getNamespaceInfo-env-quot-S3methods-quot-td4755490.html) suggests.
Then, I suddenly found many essential packages are reported broken, including `ggplot2`. I tried to reinstall it under administrative mode. It installed successfully, yet can't be load. Some others even can't be installed.

> install.packages("ggplot2")

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/eric1/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.5:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'
trying URL 'https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2018-08-01/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/ggplot2_3.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3578357 bytes (3.4 MB)
downloaded 3.4 MB

package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\eric1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgLau0F\downloaded_packages
```

> library(ggplot2)

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")):
 number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

It seems unlikely all the packages are broken within a short period, any suggestion besides reinstall the R?
Many thanks.

Comment: can you try updating R and installing up to date versions of the packages?

Comment: Thanks for advice. I am using MRO 3.5.1, now trying 3.5.3

Comment: No, It doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I am using MRO 3.5.1, now trying 3.5.3. Just tried. No, upgrading R doesn't make any difference. Seems I have to restart all over again. Sad..

Comment: I am getting the same error message, but during installation of ggplot2. Have you found the solution?

Comment: @FanweiZeng I just have a vague impression that I solved this issue by changing the user mode, like sudo, or somthing like this.

Comment: @FanweiZeng if u r at China, let me know. I am too, maybe we can share on WX

Comment: @Grec001 I am in the US. Thank you though! Somehow I was able to get it installed. I don't remember how I did that because I was trying too many things :)

Comment: @FanweiZeng Exactly what I'd been thru. ha. Glad to know you solved it. Good luck!

Comment: @Grec001 Thank you!